# Trying to use the GeoWebCache "gmaps" service

Tags: geoserver, google-maps, geowebcache

I am using GeoServer 2.4.5 with built-in GeoWebCache 1.5.0.

I'm integrating GeoServer with a Google Maps V3 api frontend, and I got it to work reasonably well using the WMS service.  However, I noticed that there's a builtin 'gmaps' service, as described here: http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.0/services/gmaps.html

I've tried to use it, with a url like:

```
http://myserver:8080/geoserver/ok/gwc/service/gmaps?layers=ok:OK_Twp&zoom=9&x=114&y=200&format=image/png
```

however, I get the following response:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://myserver:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
<ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( gmaps )</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

For some reason, it can't find the 'gmaps' service.  Any ideas?  I've made sure to enable "Global Services", but can't find any configuration regarding the gmap service in the GeoServer web interfact.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance it looks like an issue with the base URL.  Try removing the workspace name in your url(it's included in the layer name anyway) so that your URL is:

http://myserver:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/gmaps?layers=ok:OK_Twp&zoom=9&x=114&y=200&format=image/png